# Connection to Oracle from Java unreliable

Tags: java, oracle

I'm new to Java and trying to setup a connection to an Oracle database from a redhat Linux machine. I've got the connection working and can execute a simple sql script but the connection only works approx. 1 in 3 times. The error it gives and the code is below. It is quite possible this is an issue with our network but I would like to have a bit more knowledge before I raise a support case. Does anyone know why the error says "Name or service not known" for ssdb0255n21-oravip when "someserver" is what is specified in the connection?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at OracleTest.main(OracleTest.java:19)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:445)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:464)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:594)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:214)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ssdb0255n21-oravip: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:894)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1286)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1239)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1155)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1091)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:117)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:411)
    ... 13 more
```

The code I am using is this

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class OracleTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
  {
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldaps://someserver:3131/ODBF2_BLOOD_P_S_B_001,cn=OracleContext,dc=in,dc=companyname,dc=com,dc=au";

    //properties for creating connection to Oracle database
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "xxx");
    props.setProperty("password", "xxxx");

    //creating connection to Oracle database using JDBC
    System.out.println(DriverManager.getLoginTimeout());
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);

    String sql ="select sysdate as current_day from dual";

    //creating PreparedStatement object to execute query
    PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();

    while(result.next())
    {
      System.out.println("Current Date from Oracle : " +         result.getString("current_day"));
    }
    System.out.println("done");

  }
}
```

I have ORACLE_HOME set to /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64/ and have created ldap.ora and sqlnet.ora files in /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64/network/admin. Contents of these are:

sqlnet.ora

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (LDAP,TNSNAMES)
```

ldap.ora

```
DIRECTORY_SERVERS = (OID.GLB.IN.companyname.COM.AU::3131)
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = "dc=in,dc=companyname,dc=com,dc=au"
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
```

It appears to have created tnsnames.ora itself

```
ORA11 =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORA11)
 )
)
```

Comment: What's the contents of your TNSNAMES.ORA? ` java.net.UnknownHostException: ssdb0255n21-oravip: Name or service not known` would imply that it is not correctly setup. Also, try using `tnsping ssdb0255n21-oravip` and see if you can connect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated my answer with these details. I've removed our company details so if there is any inconsistencies it's most likely a typo on my behalf. I don't have a tnsping command on my box.

Comment: Your TNSNAMES.ORA is not setup correctly. The service name is `ORA11` and you're trying to connect to ssdb0255n21-oravip. Note, you probably have tnsping in your oracle\bin folder. Note, I have had a similar problem in the past and sometimes its because you have too many interfaces available. Disable one of the interfaces.

Comment: So what should I put in tnsnames.ora? I've searched the entire machine and don't have tnsping anywhere for some reason. I've just got sqlplus and genezi in the bin folder.

Comment: Forgot to mention I tried disabling every network adapter except for the Ethernet one and still no joy.

Comment: the thin client does not use the tnsnames.ora file, no?

Comment: @OldProgrammer my understanding is that no addition config files are required as everything is specified in the connection.

Comment: I've found I can connect exactly 50% of the time with SQL Plus also so it's not related to my code at least. I think it is a network fault so I have raised a ticket at work. I suspect there is a load balancer with an even number of possible hosts and I can only connect to half of them.

Comment: @kgdesouz I think tnsping must be a windows utility

Comment: Maybe you are trying to connect to an Oracle RAC. In this case the url connection is a little bit different.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to answer my own questions but it turned out not to be an issue with Oracle. It was an issue with DNS resolve failing. I put the ssdb0255n21-oravip host into the /etc/hosts file and the problem immediately went away. I suspect a load balancer somewhere is directing 50% of DNS lookups to a DNS server that is returning an error. We have a very complicated network here :-)